# How to view and edit only a small part of a text file in Emacs

Tags: emacs, editor, regions

I would like to accomplish the following behaviour in Emacs and was wondering if there's an existing package that already does what I want.

I want my buffer to display only lines 30 to 60 in file myfile.txt, and simply hide the rest of the file from me.

- When I scroll up to the top, I should be at line 30.
- When I scroll down to the bottom, I should be at line 60.
- If I edit this region, these edits should be reflected in the original file.
- The region should grow/shrink as I insert/delete lines.
- I should be able to open multiple regions to the same file in different buffers.

This is very close to my ideal workflow. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: For all but the last requirements, you have [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html).

Comment: For the last requirement, check [indirect buffers](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndirectBuffers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try library [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect) ([`narrow-indirect.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el))

It provides simple commands to create an *indirect buffer* that is a clone of the current buffer and that is narrowed to a particular portion of it.  By default, it helps you distinguish such indirect buffers from non-indirect buffers, by using a buffer-name prefix (default **`I-`**) and by using a different face for the buffer name in the mode line.

Answer (score 5):

The [Narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html),you can Narrow down to between point and mark with `C-x n n`,then what you edit will be restricted in this region,after that you just Widen to make the entire buffer accessible again `C-x n w`.Perhaps this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answers, if you are working on an **org file** specifically, you also have the [following commands](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-editing.html) :

**`C-x n s`** (`org-narrow-to-subtree`) : *Narrow buffer to current subtree.*

**`C-x n w`** (`widen`) :  *Widen buffer to remove narrowing.*

And if you are using blocks (‘#+BEGIN’ … ‘#+END) :

**`C-x n b`** (`org-narrow-to-block`) : *Narrow buffer to current block.*